# How to find the matrix given the rotation operation?

Tags: abstract-algebra, rotations

For example, Y is a $3 \times 3$ matrix representing a counterclockwise rotation of $\frac{\pi}{4}$ radians about the y-axis (assuming the positive axis is pointing towards you).

Answer (score 1):

When rotating a vector about the $y$-axis its tip traces out an arc in a plane parallel to the $xz$-plane, that is, its $x$- and $z$-coordinate change but its $y$-coordinate is unchanged. The corresponding rotation matrix is

$$
R_{y,\theta} = 
\left[
\begin{array}{ccc}
\cos\theta & 0 & -\sin\theta\\
0 & 1 & 0\\
\sin\theta & 0 & \cos\theta
\end{array}
\right]
$$

Comment: I got your idea. Thanks!